# .js file using jquery's .post - super unsecure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a lot of jquery in a .js file I have.  To add interactivity to the webpage, rather than going to a new page everytime a button is clicked, I use Jquery's "post" feature.

My code looks like this in quite a few spots:

```
$.post('post.php', {'administrator':4,'variable':variable'}, function (data) {
    do stuff depending on what data is , or display data
});
```

my post.php file is where a lot of functions are.  a few examples are, it checks to see if an email is valid, it checks to see if a phone number is already in use, it logs you in, it logs you out and other small functions like that so that when your filling out my forms the data is accurate.  I do not rely on scripting validation at all, I do all validation on the server side as well as testing for SQL injections and that kind of stuff.

My main question is:
  Is this an acceptable way to do this?  Can someone see how I'm doing that .js file and somehow use it to abuse my post.php file and gain access to information?  I'm not very good at thinking like a criminal so I'm not sure what they could do.  I'm just not familiar with how much someone could take my .js file and use it against me.  I know javascript is client side, and javascript cant access the sql database and stuff like that but I also do not want them to be able to call administrator functions (such as logging in and logging out) if there is a chance they could somehow bypass the system.  I do not use cookies to store anything.

As long as I have good security measures on my php file should I be ok?  is there a better way to check availability "on the fly" of things rather than using jquery's .post?

Comment: try to add some validation on the client. that is much faster than making a request and it increases the security. Additionally it is a convention to make validation client- and server-side.

Comment: I do have some validation on the client side I just do not solely rely on it because everywhere I read that client side stuff can always be manipulated.  If your not a malicious user a lot is validated on client side, but I have all the same validation in place on server side as well in case a user tries to be clever.  Thanks for your advice.  I'm going to double check and see if there are any spots I can use client side rather than making requests.

Comment: That's... relatively bad advice. Validation on the client is for user interface purposes only. **All** validation should be on the server, on the client it's only for convenience.

Comment: That's exactly how I approach it.  All validation on the server side, any validation on the client side is just used for convenience to the client so they have a chance to type it all correctly the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable way to do this?

Yes

> Can someone see how I'm doing that .js file and somehow use it to abuse my post.php file and gain access to information?

Any JS running on the browser is visible to the user. It may be hard to read and trace but definitely visible. That means anyone could study it under a microscope and see how it works. In addition, anyone can just shoot straight through and curl your endpoint, leaving the JS useless.

Proper authentication and sanitation will keep your PHP safe. Doing the same in your JS would improve usability as well as prevent unwanted people from seeing on the surface something they shouldn't see.

Comment: I'm always trying to read and find new ways to add security but I feel my PHP is relatively secure.  You saying this is a acceptable way to do these kinds of things makes me feel better. 

I'm not sure how to authenticate my .js file to prevent unwanted people from seeing it.  I'll have to read up on that, see what I can find.

Comment: @DerekConlon For one, you should not load privileged content (templates, logic, data) to an unprivileged user. This reduces the chances that someone unwanted could see functionality reserved to a privileged user.